# How to pass Uri value to bundle value

Tags: java, android, android-intent, uri

This following code fetches multiple contacts and stores them in a bundle:

```
 Intent phonebookIntent = new Intent("intent.action.INTERACTION_TOPMENU");
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("additional", "phone-multi");
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("maxRecipientCount", MAX_PICK_CONTACT);
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("FromMMS", true);
    startActivityForResult(phonebookIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT);
```

The code below retrieves the selected data:

```
  if (requestCode ==  REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT) {

            Uri contractData = data.getData();

            Bundle contantData =  data.getExtras();
            String result= contantData.getString("result");
            ArrayList<String> contacts = contantData.getStringArrayList("result");
            ContactRetriever cr = new ContactRetriever(getApplicationContext(), contacts);
            Person p = cr.getPerson();
```

I want the data in Uri so that I can make use of it in other classes which refer to Uri data.

How can I pass the bundle value to the Uri data?

Another example of using Uri data as "contactData":

```
private String getNumber() {
    String ret = null;


    Cursor cId = cr.query(contractData, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID}, null, null, null);

    if (cId.moveToFirst()){
        id = cId.getString(cId.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        Log.i(TAG + " IDs: ", id);
    }
    cId.close();

    Cursor cNum = cr.query(contractData, null, null, null, null);

    if (cNum.moveToNext()){
        ret = cNum.getString(cNum.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        Log.i(ret, TAG + " NUMBERS: ");
    }
    return ret;
}

private String getName() {
    String ret = null;

    Cursor c = cr.query(contractData, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst())
        ret = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

    c.close();
    Log.i(TAG + "NAMES: ", ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Specific usage of contractData examples:

```
Cursor cId = cr.query(contractData, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID}, null, null, null);

Cursor cNum = cr.query(contractData, null, null, null, null);

Cursor c = cr.query(contractData, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass the Uri as a string using the `toString` function, then parse it back as a Uri.

So, to send it as part of the URI:

```
phonebookIntent.putExtra("uri", uriData.toString());
```

To read it back:

```
Uri uriData = Uri.parse(extras.getString"uri"));
```

Comment: and in Uri uriData = Uri.parse(extras.getString"uri"));     extras error its because extras in not getting the value.

Comment: What error are you getting from uriData.toString() ? I assume that uriData is of type Uri... right?

Comment: it says its undefined..and once i have defined it I am not getting the output

Comment: When I wrote uriData that refers to your uri data parameter, i.e. the variable that is of type URI for you. You need to replace uriData with what is applicable for you. Please share your code where you used this if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 14):

Uri implements `Parcelable` so you can do it this way:

```
phonebookIntent.putExtra("uri", your_uri_object);
```

Read it back:

```
Uri uri =  getIntent().getParcelableExtra("uri");
```